# Setting jqGrid row height below 23px

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I know there are questions on here about how to set row height.  I have read them and done what they suggest, but none of them actually solve the problem I want to solve.  My users want to see more data on the grid at once.  So, I tried to change row height to something like 15px.

jqGrid ignores any row height lower than 23px.  The following code works when the height value passed in is 23 or greater:

```
self.grid.setRowData(row[self.keyColumn], false, { height: cssRowHeight });
```

Anything lower, and an inspection of the html shows that the row has a height of 21px and there is a 1px border on top and bottom.

So my question is, how can I set the jqGrid row height to a value lower than 23px?

Thanks,
Jerome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good question! I think it will be interesting for other users.

Look at [the demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SmallRowHeight.htm) which displays

[image]

I used the following CSS:

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { height: 15px; }
```

The exact results can depends from the other formetters which you use. For example the same grid where the column with `formatter: 'checkbox'` are visible (see [here](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SmallRowHeight0.htm)) looks, especially in IE, not so compact:

[image]

It's in any way compacter as the original grid (see [the demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SmallRowHeight_.htm)):

[image]

If you need reduce the size of rows having comboboxes for example you have to use additional CSS like

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { height: 15px; padding-top: 0px;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td input { padding: 0px; height: 11px; width: 11px; }
```

see [here](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SmallRowHeight1.htm).

Comment: Hello @Oleg, I have doubt on the same. I have multiple row data in same row. Lets say, in Column "Shipped Via", I have 3 values seperated by '\n' i.e. TNT,FEDEX,ABC. In this condition how to reduce the size of row and only show TNT and when the user brings mouse near to that row+coulmn, he will see all three values in tooltip. Or can we expand/shrink row on click of that row+column and make three values visible. Please reply. Thanks

Comment: @Jaikrat: Sorry, but it sounds line a new question. There are many implementation options. So you should describe more clear and in details the situation which you have. You start for example about the text with `'\n'` (not `<br/>`), but write comma separated string `TNT,FEDEX,ABC` without any `\n` or spaces later. You write about **one** item `TNT` on the first line instead of the part of text appended with `...` (like `TNT,FED...`) for example or just the text wrapping (ward wrapping or character wrapping). What is exact format of input data? What exact you want to display in jqGrid?

Comment: @Oleg, here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695021/how-to-expand-shrink-row-in-jqgrid-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Add the following css styles in your jQGrid file as inetrnal style between style tag

```
<style>
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td{height:40px;}
</style>
```

and following [link to customize grid height, width, font size and font family](http://www.smarttutorials.net/pagination-previous-next-first-and-last-button-using-jqgrid-php-mysql-jquery-and-ajax/).